# Get the last uploaded docker image from gitlab container registry

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-image, container-registry

We store docker images in gitlab container registry. The images have tags such as imagename-datetimestamp.So if an image A is built at 8 a.m on 5/21/21, it is uploaded as imagenameA-0521210800. The next one built at 12 p.m is uploaded as imagenameA-0521211200. Is there an api or command that can help me fetch the last uploaded image at any time? In this case "imagenameA-0521211200" is the last uploaded.

Note: I do not want to pull with "latest" tag.

Thanks

Comment: I presume you've tried this [List Registry Repository Tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/container_registry.html#list-registry-repository-tags)?  It's hard to write a full answer without knowing your environment, but using that to get the tags and then reading the JSON should be relatively straightforward, if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use the API to get your images tags list as per the example at https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#tags .

Then parse the result (eg. by [jq](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/jq-command-json)), sort results and invoke`docker pull` for the right **tag**.